# Using neighbors wifi; need strong signal

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a camper on vacant property that I use frequently.  I also have a neighbor that has a home roughly 150ish yards away, and yet somehow I am still getting a faint WIFI signal from his hot spot( which he says I can use).

My laptop is finding the hotspot, but it is to weak to use.  And the cell phone, will actually connect from time to time.  So my question is, is there a product I can by that will strengthen his signal in my camper, so I can access the internet?

I have looked online at extenders, repeaters, etc. And I am at a loss as to which is the best way to go.  USB WIFI Adapter? Antenna? Do I need to spend more to get better quality? Any help is appreciated, even if its just to point me in the right direction.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most popular solution is to use a "[cantenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantenna)" they are cheap and can easily be made using household materials.

What it basically does is turn a omnidirectional WiFi antenna from a cheap usb wifi adapter in to a directed one. Boosting the strength in the direction it is pointed.

Just search cantenna on Google and you will find both instructions on how to make your own or places to buy pre-made ones.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have looked into the "Cantenna" ; I have a few old routers lying around I could try.  I was just hoping to save time, and figured purchasing a specifically made product would be better.  Everything I see with extenders and boosters is that you must be able to access the router info; I am sure my neighbor would give it to me, but I dont want to hassle him.  Cantenna might be what happens.

Comment: @Phoenix: a router or access-point is a bad device to start with. You will likely not be able to tune your antenna because many access-points (AP) don't provide signal strength info. Take an AP with omni-dir. antenna and build a cantenna for an USB or PCI WiFi adapter for your tests. Use NetStumbler (W2k, WXP) or Vistumbler (Win Vista and above) to scan Wifis and monitor their signal strength. Tune your cantenna until you get the range you need. I was able to run over 1.5km very well, with little distance over the ground (you normally need some clearance to avoid interference by reflections).

Comment: I have tested cantennas from Pringles cans (quite okay) and stew (or fruit) tin cans with about 100mm diameter (really good!). Pringles have lower diameter, thus worse. But even better than cantenna and also easy to build: the wire-8 (not sure about the true name), http://lifehacker.com/5964111/diy-wi-fi-antenna-cheaply-extends-your-wireless-network. For more infos, search for "homebrew WiFi antenna" and you'll find ANY type you look for! ;-)

Comment: BTW, principals cans don't work that well for 2.4 Ghz WiFi, they are too narrow. However they are about the right size for 5.0 Ghz WiFi.